# How can I help as a developer?

Tags: discussion

I'm a Java developer. I want to help the community pro bono, please point me in the direction of a relevant project or people.

Comment: Do you mean the Skeptics site, or the community in general?

Comment: Skeptics community in general.

Answer (score 1):

As a developer you can engage in the scientific community at large.

There are many jobs and open source projects which promote and directly help science or skepticism.

Many of our fellow skeptics are part of the scientific community, I hope they can edit in a few more examples in this list:

- [Rbutr](http://blog.rbutr.com/support-rbutr/)

  rbutr is a community driven system which maps links between webpages where the content of one page is a critical response to the other. The content may be directly arguing against the original content, or generally presenting contradictory evidence.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, but a valid suggestion. I'm also going to use it for some research activities. Thanks.

Comment: @Czar can you explain better what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at some of the projects @TimFarley is talking about: [Skeptools](https://skeptools.wordpress.com/)

Comment: Great resource, thanks.