# Vote count on meta isn't the same for migrated questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

This: [How can I help as a developer?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3104/how-can-i-help-as-a-developer)
has a different vote count depending on meta/main site.

Answer (score 1):

They're presumably different questions: when a question is 'migrated' then it's **copied** to the new site (such that there are now two copies of the question, one closed and with its own vote count, and one migrated with its own independent vote count).

Comment: I'm under the impression - but can't confirm - the voting are copied across too, so you get credit for your original votes on the new site.

Comment: Yes but they're copied (so you end up with independent copies which can then diverge). FYI I think that net-positive votes are copied  (so that a question keeps its up-votes when it's migrated), but net-negative votes are reset to zero (so that if a question is down-voted for being on the wrong site, it doesn't keep those down-votes when it's migrated).

Comment: but you can 't access the original Q because you get sent to the new site

Comment: @JonMarkPerry A fictional example: a) Someone posts a question "How do ants communicate?" on Skeptics b) It's downvoted (-3) on Skeptics because it's bad question for Skeptics c) It's migrated to Biology.SE d) It's answered and upvoted (+3) on Biology.SE e) The new vote (+3) fro Biology.SE isn't migrated back to the Skeptics.SE copy of the question (it remains a bad/closed question on Skeptics.SE) f) Clicking the Skeptics.SE version of the question takes you to the Biology.SE copy (which is the only copy that may have answers. I think that's how it works and how it's supposed to work ...

Comment: ... i.e. that behaviour is 'by design' and not a bug.

Comment: what if the Skeptic version is then deleted?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Well then the other, newer, migrated, up-voted copy on Biology.SE will remain. And FWIW the original copy on Skeptics will remain too, but invisible: I think that deleted topics still exist but can only be found by people with moderator priviledges.

Comment: so you don't get your downvoted rep back twice then.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I suspect that any Skeptics.SE rep which the OP lost will be refunded, when their down-voted question is deleted on Skeptics.SE.

Answer (score 0):

Each site has a different database. When a post is migrated, the whole post, its history, its votes and metadata are duplicated in the destination tables. Only users are not copied, but merely mapped.